# Showing div in angularjs not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-ng-show

I want to show a `div` only when the function happens.

Here is the HTML, but it is always showing, I want it to show only when the function is true

```
<div ng-controller="controller">
    <div ng-show="data.show"> Successfully triggered </div>
    <div ng-hide="!(data.hide)"> Error in triggering</div>
</div>
```

In the controller I have:

```
if(results.data=='success') {
    $scope.data = {
        show: false,
        hide: true
    }; 
    //Here I should display the success message
} else {
    //Here I should display the error message
}
```

So, How can I show the success `div` in if condition and error `div` in the else condition.

**Note :** If possible if the `div` is shown in slow motion it will be very helpful for me. Like the fade timing in jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should only maintain only one flag `data.show` that is more than sufficient to show hide div.

```
<div ng-controller="controller">
    <div ng-show="data.show"> Successfully triggered </div>
    <div ng-hide="data.show"> Error in triggering</div>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function(){

   ///other stuff here ..


   $scope.myFunction = function(){
       if(results.data=='success') {
          $scope.data.show = true; //success
       } else {
          $scope.data.show = false; //error
       }
    }

    //init code here
    $scope.data = { show: false }; //this should be outside your show/hide function 

})
```

Comment: If i want to show the successfully triggered text, then should i do like this ? `$scope.data = {
            show: true,
            hide: false
        };` ?

Comment: Or may i know what should i do to show and hide it in success and failure condition ?

Comment: @Preethi you should only care about doing true false for `$scope.data = { show: true}`

Comment: @pankar : By default the `Successfully triggered` is visible, when i try to do `$scope.data = { show: true}` the message was the same and no actions was there .. :(

Comment: Yes, i am trying it.. Actually i have this in the app.js first line `function controller($scope) {
        $scope.data = {
            show: true,
            hide: false
        };
    }` Is that araise any problem ?

Comment: Because without the above code, i am getting errors in my console when the page is render itself

Comment: I have this error when i try the updated code ... after the button press `Cannot set property 'show' of undefined`

Comment: @Preethi read my 1st line carefully you should write `$scope.data = { show: false };` line in you controller somewhere,,and then you need to use `if(results.data=='success') {
    $scope.data.show = true; //success
} else {
    $scope.data.show = false; //error
}` in your function

Comment: sorry, when i put this `$scope.data = { show: false };` at the first line of the controller, it shows me this error `Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.16/ng/areq?p0=controller&p1=not%20aNaNunction%2C%20got%20undefined
    at Error (native)` and displaying both the div elements in the html page

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82333/discussion-between-preethi-and-pankajparkar).

Comment: Hi, another help, can you help me pls http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31218982/post-not-working-as-expected-in-angularjs  i already posted it in my friend account, i will accept that. but can you help me in this pls....

Answer (score 0):

I would use one div something like the following

```
<div ng-controller="controller">
    <div ng-show="data.show">{{data.message}}</div>
</div>
```

Get rid of your hide property on data it isn't needed and set your text in the controller on another data property.  The bottom line is data.show has to be "truthy" for the div to show up.  Honestly, if you are always going to show a div I would get rid of ng-show and just dynamically set the div content in the controller.

Comment: Can't i use without `{{` because i am using laravel which will have conflict with that..

Comment: To get around the handlebars maybe take a look at ng-if directive?

Answer (score 0):

here is my example: [Example for show div on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/16894/)

```
 <div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="showCtrl">
      <div>Show Div:
          <button ng-click="set()"></button>
        <div ng-show="showDiv"> Successfully triggered </div>
        <div ng-hide="showDiv"> Error in triggering</div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want to add fade in and fade out timing, I suggest you to look up angular animate. [Documentation and example for angular animate.](http://www.nganimate.org/angularjs/ng-repeat/move)

Answer (score 0):

wow, there are already so many answers, and they are all correct. Everybody also rightly pointed out that to have a little animation, you can use ngAnimate.

My little jsFiddle is here, just as a fun little exercise.

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate']);

app.controller('testCtrl', function ($scope) {
 $scope.data = {
        show:true,
        hide: false
 }; 

$scope.go = function(checked) {
    $scope.data = {
        show:!checked,
        hide: checked
 }; 
 }

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dshun/j8wgnnm5/13/